# Would tipped pass be a 2 or 3 pointer?

Tags: rules, officiating, basketball

I was playing in a basketball league that follows NCAA rules. A scenario happened where we players and referees did not know the exact answer and cannot find a specific rule explanation online.

My teammate threw an oop pass from beyond the 3 point line to me. I went to jump to catch it but was below the hoop. The defender jumped with me and tipped it in; I had no contact with the ball.

Would it be considered a 3 pointer since I did not touch it and the pass came beyond the 3 point line, or would it be ruled a 2 since it was a pass and the defender accidentally tipped it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the fact that the pass originated from beyond the 3-point line matters much here.  The pass couldn't have been on target as a 3-point try or the opponent would have been called for goaltending.

So it's just someone making an own goal, which is always worth 2 points.  That falls under the [NCAA rules](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/BR17.pdf) Rule 5, Section 1, Article 4a

> a. When a player scores a field goal in the opponent’s basket, it shall count two points for the opponent regardless of the location on the playing court from where it was released. Such a field goal shall not be credited to a player in the scorebook but shall be indicated with a footnote.